# How to display all forms within the app as readonly?

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-3, readonly

I have an MVC3 application (MVC3, EF 4.3.1, nInject) with quite complex database structure.
Let's say the simplified data model looks like this:

```
MainObject
- SubObject1
- SubObject2
- SubObject3
```

The application has many pages which contain html forms that allow to make changes to the properties of all objects (including MainObject). Sometimes there are forms that allow to change only a few properties of an object and then there is another form that makes it possible to change the rest (or not).

Now, I want to add a property `ReadOnly` to MainObject. If it's set to true, I want to show all forms related to this object as read-only (also forms for SubObjects).

Obviously I want to do it with as little effort as possible. I know I could add a `ReadOnly` property to the view models and then specify readonly for all input fields, but I am looking for something more generic and less labor-intense...).

To tell truth I don't know from which side to approach the problem, so I am looking forward to your ideas.